# SQL script behaves differently depending on whether it's run on DB host or from another host

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the a sql file containing the following:
Note that the CDB column in v$database only exists when version (not Oracle but of some other unrelated product) is greater than 11.

It runs fine when I execute it on DB host using sqlplus 
    sqlplus / as sysdba @abc.sql 1000 60 10

However, when I connect to this DB host remotely using connection string, it complains about "Invalid identifier" if CDB column does not exist (no matter what version value I specify)

```
Connected to: 
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production 
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage 
Management, Oracle Label Security, 
OLAP, Data Mining, Oracle Database Vault and Real Application Testing options 
. 
old   2:  num_ret_period NUMBER(9) := 
new   2:  num_ret_period NUMBER(9) := 43200; 
old   3:  num_interval NUMBER(9) := 
new   3:  num_interval NUMBER(9) := 60; 
old   5:  lcm_version NUMBER(4) := 
new   5:  lcm_version NUMBER(4) := 1; 
    SELECT CDB INTO isCDB from v$database; 
           * 
ERROR at line 10: 
ORA-06550: line 10, column 12: 
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CDB": invalid identifier 
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5: 
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Any ideas why?

```
DECLARE
 num_ret_period NUMBER(9) := &1;
 num_interval NUMBER(9) := &2;
 isCDB VARCHAR2(10);
 version NUMBER(4) := &3;

BEGIN

  IF version > 11 THEN
    SELECT CDB INTO isCDB from v$database;
    IF (isCDB = 'YES') THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER session SET CONTAINER = CDB$ROOT';
      dbms_output.put_line('CDB is set to YES');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('CDB is set to NO');
    END IF;
  END IF;

  callSomeProcedure();

  commit;
EXCEPTION
            when others then
                    dbms_output.put_line('There is an exception in abc.sql' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
                    ROLLBACK;
                    raise_application_error(-20001, 'There is an exception in abc.sql' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);

    END;
    /
```

Comment: When you say "It runs fine when I execute it on DB host"  is you ORACLE_SID (or TWO_TASK) set to a 12c DB? What does the banner show then?

Comment: Added clarification. Version is not related to Oracle but some other product that I'm passing via argument.

Comment: The database version matters though. It will compile in a 12c database, but not in an 11g database, which is what your output shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you do not intend to execute the code guarded by `if version > 11` it still needs to be parsed. At this point the fact that `CDB` does not exist (version 11) is revealed.

To avoid this, use conditional compilation:

```
$IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VER_LE_11 $THEN
   -- version 11 code
   NULL;
$ELSE
   -- version 12 and later code
   NULL;
$END
```

The conditional compilation directives act similar to a preprocessor.

See https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/conditional-compilation-10gr2

Comment: Thanks but the version is not for Oracle but for some other unrelated product.

Comment: @Pha3drus - you can still use conditional compilation around the 12c-specific code, i.e. the CDB check - as well as, or instead of, whatever else your unrelated version check is for. In your code it does appear to be related to the DB version though.

Comment: @Pha3drus - Would like me to expand the example and clarify?